# Reading strings from text files using switch -regex returns null element

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

## Question:

The intention of my script is to filter out the name and phone number from both text files and add them into a hash table with the name being the key and the phone number being the value.

The problem I am facing is 
`$name = $_.Current` is returning `$null`, as a result of which my hash is not getting populated.

Can someone tell me what the issue is?

## Contents of File1.txt:

Lori

234 east 2nd street

Raleigh nc 12345

9199617621

lori@hotmail.com

=================

## Contents of File2.txt:

Robert

2531 10th Avenue

Seattle WA 93413

2068869421

robert@hotmail.com

## Sample Code:

```
$hash = @{}

Switch -regex (Get-content -Path C:\Users\svats\Desktop\Fil*.txt)

{

'^[a-z]+$' { $name = $_.current} 

'^\d{10}'  {   
         $phone = $_.current
         $hash.Add($name,$phone)
         $name=$phone=$null
       }
default
       {
write-host "Nothing matched"
       }

}
$hash
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `current` property reference from `$_`:

```
$hash = @{}

Switch -regex (Get-content -Path C:\Users\svats\Desktop\Fil*.txt)
{
    '^[a-z]+$' { 
        $name = $_
    } 

    '^\d{10}'  {
        $phone = $_
        $hash.Add($name, $phone)
        $name = $phone = $null
    }
    default {
        Write-Host "Nothing matched"
    }

}
$hash
```

Answer (score 2):

[Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40539563/45375) explains your problem and offers an effective solution:
**it is automatic variable `$_` / `$PSItem` *itself* that contains the current input object** (whatever its type is - what properties `$_` / `$PSItem` has therefore depends on the input object's specific type).

---

Aside from that, there's potential for **making the code both less verbose and more efficient**:

```
# Initialize the output hashtable.
$hash = @{}

# Create the regex that will be used on each input file's content.
# (?...) sets options: i ... case-insensitive; m ...  ^ and $ match
# the beginning and end of every *line*.
$re = [regex] '(?im)^([a-z]+|\d{10})$'

# Loop over each input file's content (as a whole, thanks to -Raw).
Get-Content -Raw File*.txt | foreach {
  # Look for name and phone number.
  $matchColl = $re.Matches($_)
  if ($matchColl.Count -eq 2) { # Both found, add hashtable entry.
    $hash.Add($matchColl.Value[0], $matchColl.Value[1])
  } else {
    Write-Host "Nothing matched."
  }
}

# Output the resulting hashtable.
$hash
```

---

A note on the construction of the .NET `[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]` object (or `[regex]` for short), `[regex] '(?im)^([a-z]+|\d{10})$'`:

Embedding matching options `IgnoreCase` and `Multiline` as *inline* options `i` and `m` directly in the regex string (`(?im`) is convenient, in that it allows using simple cast syntax (`[regex] ...`) to construct the regular-expression .NET object.

However, this syntax may be obscure and, furthermore, not all matching options are available in inline form, so here's the more verbose, but easier-to-read equivalent:

```
$re = New-Object regex -ArgumentList '^([a-z]+|\d{10})$', 'IgnoreCase, Multiline'
```

Note that the two options must be specified comma-separated, as a *single* string, which PowerShell translates into the bit-OR-ed values of the corresponding enumeration values.

Comment: Thanks Mkelement i will try running it. In your regex what does "im" means ?

Comment: They are _matching options_ (the specific ones are already explained in the code comments) - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx See also my update on how to construct the regex object more verbosely, which is easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

other solution, use convertfrom-string

```
 $template=@'
 {name*:Lori}
 {street:234 east 2nd street}
 {city:Raleigh nc 12345}
 {phone:9199617621}
 {mail:lori@hotmail.com}
 {name*:Robert}
 {street:2531 10th Avenue}
 {city:Seattle WA 93413}
 {phone:2068869421}
 {mail:robert@hotmail.com}
 {name*:Robert}
 {street:2531 Avenue}
 {city:Seattle WA 93413}
 {phone:2068869421}
 {mail:robert@hotmail.com}
 '@


 Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\file*.txt" | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | select name, phone
```